# Folder hierarchy of bookmarks in Android Browser

Tags: android, database, android-contentprovider, bookmarks, android-browser

I am developing an application for bookmarks management. Currently, I am displaying all the bookmarks in the `listview`. This approach works well if the number of bookmarks is small. But if there are large number of bookmarks, then the list becomes too long and difficult to locate a particular bookmark. So, I want the user to be able to create folders and move respective bookmarks to the folders. As there is no folder column in the Android bookmarks database, I can't store the information of which bookmarks belongs to which folder.

I can create my own database and maintain this information but then the folder hierarchy won't be visible to the Android. How can I create this folder hierarchy and store this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As there is no folder column in the Android bookmarks database, I
>   can't store the information of which bookmarks belongs to which
>   folder.

But there is. Pulled out the database of browser from emulator running 4.0 and it has a folder field

[image]
but when i checked in 2.3 it does not have such a field and I think the application (Bookmarks sort and backup) you mentioned in comment only gives this functionality in 4.0 and above . You can look into the source code also if you are curious the part where the folder is added to db .

```
  values.put(BrowserContract.Bookmarks.PARENT, mCurrentFolder);
```

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/browser/AddBookmarkPage.java#AddBookmarkPage

Hope This helps.

Comment: I observed the same behavior with 4.0 and 2.3 but didn't check the database. And it's clearly visible that there is a folder column in bookmarks database in 4.0 and above. Anyways thanks for the answer. It will solve my problem.

Comment: Were you able to change the value in folder coulmn? I tried to change it, but it just did not let me change it(I could change every other though)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "but then the folder hierarchy won't be visible to the android"? That your hierarchy is not visible in the stock or chrome browser? Well, of course not. They simply do not support hierarchical information because they use the Browser content provider.

But your app might still use them. You would have to keep your database in sync with the content provider by adding a content observer and by resyncing when your app starts afresh (e.g. after a reboot or after it was destroyed by Android to free up resources).

I can imagine that this kind of app makes sense - especially on tablets where people tend to surf (and thus bookmark) more. Be prepared though that Google might add hierarchies to the Browser content provider in future releases. I think they eventually have to do so.

Comment: look I was under the same impression that your folder hierachy can never be visible to the android and hence I created my own database for bookmarks which is in sync with the android's bookmarks database. But then I saw an app(Bookmarks sort and backup) in which you can create folders and keep your bookmarks there and when you access those bookmarks from the android's default browser the bookmarks were displayed in the same order. So, I think it's possible. I tried looking in the android's documentation for some hint but couldn't find any and hence the question.

Comment: Interesting. I will have a look at the Browser provider later on.